# Will Specific Operators give me different results?

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, operators

I'm working in my Sam's teach yourself work book, in lesson 5 the workshop asks to show the results of 32/7 and 32.0/7. Will the use of different operators such as float or int give me different results. I attempted in my code, but it resulted in an error. Could you point me in the right direction??

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1 = 32, num2 = 32.0, num3 = 7;
    int result = num1/num3;
    float result2 = num2/num3;

    cout << result << endl;
    cout << result2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use a cast: `float result2 = (float)num2/(float)num3;`

Comment: When both the operands are `int`, the result is only the quotient of the division. When one of them is `float` ,you get the actual result

Comment: “it resulted in an error” What error? A compile-time error? A run-time error? It did not work as you intended? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared all the three numbers `num1`, `num2` and `num3` as `int`, so they will behave as integers. You may probably want `num2` to be declared as a `float` for `result2` to store a `float` value. When two `ints` are divided, they will result in an `int`, and after that if you store the result in a `float`, it will only result in a `floating point` representation of the integer result. Eg : for `result2`, `num2/num3` will be `32/7` which will be equal to `4` as an integer. Now, since it has to be stored in a `float` (reading the expression from right to left), it will be typecasted as `4.000000`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num1 = 32, num2 = 32.0, num3 = 7;
```

In this line of code, you have tried to assign 32.0(a floating number) to an integer data type, which is illegal. So try this to understand

```
cout<<32/7<<endl;
cout<<32.0/7<<endl;
```